# How to open ssh and launch a command at the same time?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have an application (Java, but could be anything else) which needs to launch another application. This is not on the same machine.

Manually, I would launch the application in this way:

```
ssh myself@machine -X
/..../myapplication
```

I tried to put the two commands in a text file called `mycommand` and

```
source mycommand
```

...but the second command will be executed on the local machine just after having closed the SSH section.

Do you know if there is a way to open an ssh and launch an application from the other machine at the same time without the user intervention?

Comment: Also worth noting that `-X` is only needed if the application uses X11 forwarding (i.e. a GUI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If after the command you don't need to execute other command in the SSH shell, you can use the following command

```
ssh myself@machine -X myapplication
```

The shell will execute the command and then close the ssh connection

Comment: Another hint: you should use -t for interactive commands. For example: "ssh home -t vim" works great but just "ssh home vim" doesn't behave as expected. You can do cool stuff with "ssh $host -t screen ..."